# Force load iframe inside wordpress not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpbakery

I want to use this code inside wpbakery to force-load an iframe each time the page refreshes. iT worked on html site now it is not working says:

**Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function** regarding this line

```
iframe = $('#firstPage');
```

the full code is this...

```
<iframe id="thirdPage" height="1270" width="1800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
           
           <script>
               
                var d = null;
  var iframe = null;
  d= new Date();
  var unique = d.getTime();
  
     unique++;
    iframe = $('#thirdPage');
    iframe.attr('src','https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html?g='+unique);

              </script>
```

Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add jQuery to your page. Try like this:

```html
<iframe id="thirdPage" height="1270" width="1800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
           
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
               
  var d = null;
  var iframe = null;
  d= new Date();
  var unique = d.getTime();
  
  unique++;
  iframe = $('#thirdPage');
  iframe.attr('src','https://www.ubs.com/global/en.html?g='+unique);

</script>
```